# Can we pass a gitlab variable with multiple elements to a shell script

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a gitlab variable as below:

`REGIONS: us-east-1 us-west-2 eu-central-1`

I want to pass this gitlab variable to a shell script. But when I pass it to script,  its fetching only first element and rest are ignored.
The code used to pass variable is:
`test.sh $REGIONS`

Is it not possible to pass it like that or is there a way for it. Please help.

Comment: Is `us-east-1 us-west-2 eu-central-1` supposed to be three separate values in an collection or one long value?

Comment: @Daly: In script it will loop through each regions.  If I directly hard code this in code, it works.

Comment: Try surrounding the value in quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `REGIONS="us-east-1 us-west-2 eu-central-1"`, then calling

```
test.sh $REGIONS
```

means that

- `us-east-1` will be assigned to the first positional parameter `$1`
- `us-west-2` will be assigned to `$2`
- `eu-central-1` will be assigned to `$3`

All the variables can be get using `$@`, but a simpler solution would be quoting the variable:

```
test.sh "$REGIONS"
```

In this case `$1` will contain `us-east-1 us-west-2 eu-central-1`